# Optimization for making a null class in a one-hot pixel-wise label

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, computer-vision, array-broadcasting

I'm preparing data for an image segmentation model. I have 5 classes per pixel that do not cumulatively cover the entire image so I want to create a 'null' class as the 6th class. Right now I have a one-hot encoded ndarray and a solution that makes a bunch of Python calls that I am looking to optimize. 
My sketch code right now:

```
arrs.shape
(25, 25, 5)

null_class = np.zeros(arrs.shape[:-1])
for i in range(arrs.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arrs.shape[1]):
        if not np.any(arrs[i][j] == 1):
            null_class[i][j] = 1
```

Ideally, I find a few-line and much more performant way of computing the null examples - my actual training data comes in 20K x 20K images and I'd like to compute and store all at once. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this with a combination of [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`numpy.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html). Using `all` to check for all zeros along the last dimension will give you a boolean array that is `True` where the `null_class` should be `1`. I will use a `(2,2,5)` array for the sake of display.

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(2,2,5))
null_class = np.zeros(arr.shape[:-1])
arr[0, 0] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
arr
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]])
np.all(arr[:, :] == 0, axis=2)
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
np.where(np.all(arr[:, :] == 0, axis=2))
(array([0]), array([0]))
null_class[np.where(np.all(arr[:, :] == 0, axis=2)] = 1
null_class
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: This is great and I learned that np.all and np.where have axis parameters from your code, but I actually found a more clear, albeit less memory efficient, solution.